# Laravel create date from string

Tags: datetime, laravel-5, php-carbon

I have a calendar that posts the value in the following format

```
3 January, 2017
```

and when I convert it to carbon by doing

```
 $carbon =   Carbon::parse($data['due_date']);
 echo $carbon;
```

I see **2016-01-03 20:17:00**
My expected output is **2017-01-03**

Answer (score 2):

Try

`$date = Carbon::createFromFormat('j F, Y', $data['due_date']);`

Answer (score 0):

Just use this

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('3 January, 2017'));
```